# sqlite, method for reindexing table in large database

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with one table `my_table`, which consists of two hundred million rows. It's structured like this:

```
index1 | column_one
______  _______
0      |AA
1      |AB
2      |CD
3      |FFF
4      |AA
...    |...
2902   |TF
....   |...
```

There problem I am facing here is, the database is really huge and it takes minutes for getting needed operations done. I have found I could do the job much faster, if I would reindex `my_table` such as:

```
 reindex  | index1 | column_one
 _________  ______  _______
  0       | 0      |AA
  1       | 1      |AB
  2       | 2      |CD
  3       | 3      |FFF
  0       | 4      |AA
  ...     | ...    |...
  8       | 2902   |TF
  ....    | ....   |...
```

This 'reindexed' value would really save me, cause it gives me an option to receive needed info within the table in miliseconds, just what I need. But I right now don't see any solution how I could do this, considering table has 200 million rows and memory limits me very much.

just to see how many different classifiers I have with `column_one`:

```
SELECT count(distinct column_one) from my_table;
```

would take two minutes :)

Comment: 1) What `SELECT` or other 'needed operations' do you perform? 2) Does your table have any indexes?

Comment: @LutzHorn . It's structured as it is written above. I use database for python, where I do further data manipulation. But to do that, I need to structure in a way of re-indexing.

Comment: Do you have an [index](https://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) on `column_one`?

Comment: How many distinct values are there? Would a list of those fit into memory?

Comment: @LutzHorn I have added one now, but how could I access index value... as far documentation says, you can only do indexed by indexname

Comment: @CL. Well I have many columns. In one column less than 1000, in others about million....

Comment: Show the actual queries that you want to speed up.

Comment: @CL. I have did: create index indexone on my_table(column_one); now I would like to call index value: select column_one.index from my_table where column_one = 'FFF'. Is something like this possible? This would be perfect

Comment: This query is efficient if there is an index on `column_one`. What do you need `reindex` for?

Comment: @CL. I need reindexed value, because I have large dataset. And re.-indexed value is very important for further development in python. Rowid is not an option, however select column_one.index from my_table where column_one = 'FFF'. is useless as well, it throws me syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, I misread you query. An index is just an ordered list of the indexed column(s), with pointers back to the original table rows.

Comment: @CL. Would this be possible to solve with any other method perhaps? Or should i create new columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to compute this number by counting all smaller values:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET reindex = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_one)
               FROM MyTable AS T2
               WHERE T2.column_one < MyTable.column_one);
```

This does the entire count independently for every row, so it is not very efficient.

It might be a better idea to retrieve a list of all values in order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_one
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY column_one;
```

… and then update the table for each such value with the index in the list.

Comment: I have been playing around with this, and I think it will work. Thank you.